# i can't shade smooth even after merging normals

Tags: normals

I was creating the donut from blender guru after , but i ran into a problem , i cannot shade smooth , i know how to fix this this , modeling tab > mesh > normal > merge , but that doesn't work , i have already tried it , this has a 2 level subsurf
**i dont think the icing is shaded smooth but the donuts main body is shaded smooth properly**[image]

**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a7g8XB9YDEzbGKZA14qlZ2YQ2rl7hh1y/view?usp=sharing**

**cannot upload a blend file through the usuall way , giving google drive file**

Comment: Probably something to do with your topology, try adding a subsurf and see if that makes it any better.

Comment: i have already tried it , this has a 2 level subsurf

Comment: Could you show us the wireframe / modifier stack, if it's not applied?

Comment: have you checked if you had the "auto smooth" enabled and if it is, if the angle wasn't too small ?

Comment: i have auto smooth enabled with 30deg

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: cant upload , its 36 mb , it only allows a 30 mb file

Comment: what else can be done??

Comment: google drive???

Comment: Google drive eventually, or delete some not important parts before uploading

Comment: You have added bevel along all edges... so that can't be smoothed...

Comment: can you elaborate , so that i cant improve

Comment: Each part that should be 1 edge is made of 4 edges (look in edit mode). So they make flat parts/bands... they'lll stay visible.

Comment: okay , before applying modifiers , this wasn't there , so how should i rectify or should i start making a whole new icing , you can also write this in the awnseres

Comment: Think remaking it will be quicker...Probably, what you missed about modifiers was to use Bevel with the *angle* option only.