# My donut is not shaded smooth

Tags: modeling, smooth

[image]

Blender file  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y51EyPONaHkKN7OexRVOLTltCTImMOIK/view?usp=sharing

I'm using the Blender version of 3.3.1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194662/i-cant-shade-smooth-even-after-merging-normals

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Andreas Kanellopoulos gives you the good answer, but you can keep both the 2 values at 2 and shade smooth your object instead. Also put the Solidify above the Subdivision Surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are usign a subdivision surface modifier with 4 levels for the view and only 2 for the render. It will look identical to the viewport if you increase the number of subdivisions for the render to 4 as well.

Comment: The problem has been fixed by your suggestion, Thank you

Comment: @Gary Even if this solved the problem to some extent: One should never prefer a subdivision to the possibility of achieving a smoothing by correct alignment of the normals. The answer of *Christopher Bennet* is therefore the way to go.

Comment: Odd that it'd even let you use a higher number in view than in render.  Can't think of any reason why you'd *want* that.  If anything it'd usually be the other way around...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's just so you can preview whether or not you actually need whatever respective subdiv level in the render - It would take a long time to have to do a full render to see if the SubSurf is "working" the way you want it to or not at whatever level. Since the viewport (by default) uses far fewer samples than a full render, it is much faster to preview even higher levels in the viewport first.

Answer (score 9):

Increasing subdivision levels to add "smoothness" is a less than ideal solution, especially in this case where a proper "shade smooth" operation would smooth out an object that has even less subdivisions than the original.

To smooth out the object, simply right-click the object and select "Shade Smooth" from the list. You can see in the example, I actually *decreased* the subdivision levels and it still works:

[image: SMooth]

Increasing subdivisions will make things look smoother, but will add a lot of unnecessary geometry to your scene which will add up over time.